# Application becomes unresponsive after encountering an exception

Tags: angular

How to tell Angular 2 to not block the whole application when it encounters an exception?

I'm not sure if it's even possible, because Google didn't enlighten me on this.
But it seems critical to any single page web application.

Whenever Angular 2 encounters an exception and throws an error, the complete application becomes unresponsive.

I know that in JavaScript

```js
try {
  doSomething();
}
catch(err) {
  handleErrors(err);
}
```

might solve the problem.

But I just want to know if there is any Angular specific solution or workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836172/angular-2-doesnt-update-view-after-exception-is-thrown#answer-43796615

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On angular 2 final version, you can implement custom `ErrorHandler` ([Angular 2 docs example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html)):

```
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';

class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE:**

[2.0.0 RC.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31) changed the name from `ExceptionHandler` to `ErrorHandler` and `call` to `handleError`:

```ts
@Injectable()
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}


@NgModule({
  directives: [MyApp],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See also [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html).

**ORIGINAL:**

Implement [a custom exception handler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ExceptionHandler-class.html):

```ts
@Injectable()
class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}


@NgModule({
  directives: [MyApp],
  providers: [
    {provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

See also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6865) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6565).

I haven't tried myself if this allows the application to continue after an exception, but I think it's worth a try. 
At least reloading the page automatically should be possible.

Generally, an exception should be handled as close as possible to the cause when there is a way to recover.

Comment: I tried it and successfully redirected to non error prone homepage, which is better than nothing. But I haven't found a way to let the application stay responsive even after exception, 
which is in general wouldn't be a good way but as a fallback it could be nice to have.

Comment: I guess there is no other way than catching the exception earlier. The exception bubbles up to Angular and Angular has no way to know how to handle your custom "bug". It runs your exception handler and exits.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to implement Custom Exception Handler as directed by **@GünterZöchbauer**

and this worked for me

---

*Bootstrap your application with `CustomExceptionHandler`.*

```ts
import {ExceptionHandler} from 'angular2/core';

class _ArrayLogger {
  res = [];

  log(s:any):void {
    this.res.push(s);
  }
  logError(s:any):void {
    this.res.push(s);
  }
  logGroup(s:any):void {
    this.res.push(s);
  }
  logGroupEnd() {
    if(this.res.length) {

      //this section executes if any error is logged by angular. 

      //do your stuff here

      /*e.g

        if(location.pathname !== 'dashboard') {
           window.location.href = '/dashboard'; // condition is required to prevent infinite loop
        }

        */
     }
  };
}

export class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  constructor() {
    super(new _ArrayLogger(), true);
  }

  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    super.call(error, stackTrace, reason);
  }
}

bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: CustomExceptionHandler})])
```

Comment: I assume you still have to reload all components. Have you tried?

Comment: yes , in `logGroupEnd() {  if(this.res.length) {` I've to do   `window.location.href = '/'` or some other defaullt path

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might occur when you're using RxJS Observables, which unsubscribe when they encounter any error.
If that's the case for you, you might need to:

1. Catch the exception within the `.subscribe`'s `onNext` handler with `try...catch` instead of inside `onError` handler.
2. Re-subscribe in `.subscribe`'s `onError` handler.

Comment: How to access this onNext handler. Could you elaborate the syntax?

Comment: @jackOfAll Sure. When you have an Observable object, then you can call a `subscribe` method on it, i.e.: `observable.subscribe(myHandler)`. `subscribe` method actually takes 3 arguments. The first one is called `onNext`, 2nd - `onError` and 3rd - `onCompleted`. You can see more here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md . Don't hesitate to ask if you have any more questions or if my answer doesn't cover what you meant :)

Comment: Thanks Michal. I tried wrapping the entire subscribe method in a try catch block. I also tried placing the code withing each callback arguments(onNext and onError, I haven't explored onCompleted ) within try catch blocks. But in each of the case I could not catch the exception! In my case the crash is happening when I get a 404 response from my API and I end up in the onError callback