# "Uncaught EXCEPTION" in view binding brings down entire Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

My template contains an expression that produces an exception:

```
<h1>Foo: {{model.somebodyForgotToInitializeMe.foo}}</h1>
```

An error the model produces the following output on the console:

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null in [
                {{model.somebodyForgotToInitializeMe.foo}}
             in SomeView@21:73]
```

That's not surprising. What *is* surprising is that this error brings down the entire Angular 2 application. Nothing else in the app responds after this has happened.

Is there a global exception handler I need to installed to prevent an error in a single binding expression killing my entire app?

This is a large medical application worked on by [alot of developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRmw7.gif). An exception in a UI component shouldn't take down the entire application.

Comment: As of now bindings in Angular2 do not fail silently like Angular1. You need to use elvis operator is bindings `{{model.somebodyForgotToInitializeMe?.foo}}`

Comment: Its good to go with `global exception handle` but please note this doesn't happen in Angular2 as you mentioned, there must be some other problem I guess. Good to go with `Elvis Operator`.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238428/how-to-tell-angular-to-not-block-the-whole-application-when-it-encounters-an-exc), might help with your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have one hack
`<h1>Foo: {{(model.somebodyForgotToInitializeMe || {}).foo}}</h1>`
We use `OR` here when the variable is not available it used `{}` (blank object).