# Custom ExceptionHandler change detection lag

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a custom `ExceptionHandler` in an Angular 2 app which submits uncaught errors to a custom `AlertsService`. The goal is to allow the main `App` component to subscribe to the alerts provided by the `AlertsService` so that it can display the errors in the UI.

The problem I'm seeing is that errors submitted to the `AlertsService` by the custom `ExceptionHandler` are not reflected in the UI until another error is encountered. This causes the UI to always be one alert behind what is actually being provided by the `AlertsService`.

My guess is that this behavior has something to do with change detection and the special case of the ExceptionHandler, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Looking to the Angular2 experts for help!

Sample code below, plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPoWCELA9IHqeLBS4wXs?p=preview):

```
import { Component, ExceptionHandler, Injectable, OnInit, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'

export interface Alert {
  message: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AlertsService {

  private alertTriggeredSubject = new Subject<Alert>();

  alertTriggered = this.alertTriggeredSubject.asObservable();

  triggerAlert(message: string) {
    this.alertTriggeredSubject.next(<Alert>{ message: message });
  }

}

@Injectable()
export class CustomExceptionHander {

  constructor(private alertsService: AlertsService) { }

  call(exception, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    this.alertsService.triggerAlert(exception.originalException);
    console.error('EXCEPTION:', exception);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template : `
  <h3>Child</h3>
  <div id="child">
    <button (click)="breakMe()">Break Me!</button>
    <div>Alerts Sent:</div>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let error of errors">{{error}}</li></ul>
  </div>`
})
export class ChildComponent {

  errors: string[] = [];
  numErrors = 0

  breakMe() {
    this.numErrors++;
    let error = `I broke it (${this.numErrors})`;

    // The error added to the array below is never reflected in the 
    // "Alerts Sent:" <ul>...not sure why
    this.errors.push(error);
    console.info('ChildComponent.errors', this.errors);

    // Simulate unhandled exception
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `
  <h3>Parent</h3>
  <div id="parent">
    <div>Alerts Received:</div>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let alert of alerts">{{alert.message}}</li></ul>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </div>`
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  constructor(private alertsService: AlertsService) { }

  alerts: Alert[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.alertsService.alertTriggered.subscribe(alert => {
      this.alerts.push(alert);

      // Alert gets received, but is not reflected in the UI
      // until the next alert is received, even thought the 
      // alerts[] is up-to-date.
      console.info('App alert received:', alert);
      console.info('App.alerts:', this.alerts);
    });
  }
}

bootstrap(App, [
    AlertsService,
    provide(ExceptionHandler, { useClass: CustomExceptionHander })
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**update** `ExceptionHandler` was renamed to `ErrorHandler` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239028/217408

**orgiginal**

Change detection isn't run at the end of the `click` event when the handler throws.

You can invoke change detection manually but this gets a bit complicated because you need an `ApplicationRef` reference and `ApplicationRef` depends on `ExceptionHandler` which makes a neat cycle and DI can't resolve cyclic dependencies.

A workaround is to instead of `ApplicationRef` inject the `Injector` and acquire `AplicationRef` imperatively like

```ts
constructor(private alertsService: AlertsService, injector:Injector) { 
  setTimeout(() => this.appRef = injector.get(ApplicationRef));
}
```

and then in `call` invoke change detection like

```ts
call(exception, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
  this.alertsService.triggerAlert(exception.originalException);
  this.appRef.tick();
  console.error('EXCEPTION:', exception);
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/n6kyWWc7dlVsfETA9lGm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, if I understand this correctly, you updated the exception handler to manually trigger change detection to handle cases where change detection wasn't triggered because of the exception? Not exactly intuitive, but it works.

Comment: I guess it is safe to do an extra change detection cycle after an exception. It shouldn't be too frequently ;-) There might be a better way. I'm not an expert in custom exception handler implementation.

Comment: One follow on question before I mark this accepted. Also, in the button click handler the error is pushed to the ChildComponent's errors[]. This value is never updated in the UI even though we're now manually run change detection in the ExceptionHandler. Any idea why?

Comment: I missed that part. I couldn't find a way to make this component update. This might be worth a bug report. I don't know what the expected behavior here is.

Comment: I saw a comment to an issue recently where they say that exceptions need to be handled locally where they appear. `ExceptionHandler` is just for unhandled exceptions for central error logging. You shouldn't rely on your application still working properly after the `ExceptionHandler` was invoked.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you know how to achieve this using Angular 5? Seems that [`ApplicationRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef) became an interface and the `Injector` fails with something like `Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError[ApplicationRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ApplicationRef!`...

Comment: I haven't seen anything related in the changelog and in the source it's still a class https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L364

Comment: The example in the plunker shows a single change detection tick, it doesn't do more than one. See this forked plunker example where UI changes don't happen after the first exception (press do it after break me): [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FJ3CskXeudz3MekC5QIR?p=preview)

Comment: You shouldn't assume the app to be in a working state after the exceptiin handler was called. You can send information to a server about the exception, you can inform the user that the app crashed and needs to be reloaded and then reload. The exception handler is not supposed to keep the app running.