# How do I override the Angular 2 Exception Handler?

Tags: angular

It looks like the old way of doing that was this:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provide(ExceptionHandler, { useClass: CustomExceptionHander })
])
```

How do you do it in the app.module.ts (post rc-5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update** `ExceptionHandler` was renamed to `ErrorHandler` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239028/217408

**orgiginal**

The syntax you use was deprecated a while ago and was removed in recent versions already.
Use object literal syntax like this instead:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: CustomExceptionHander }],
  ...
})
```

Comment: thank you, that works as long as I'm not trying to inject another service into it.  Once I add a service to the constructor though, I'm getting: `Can't resolve all parameters for MadaketExceptionHandler: (?).`

Comment: You need to add the providers for the parameters as well to the `providers: []` of the module. I would need to see more details to give more concrete feedback.

Comment: yes, I've done that.  Thanks for your help there.  This is a different issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576701/angular-2-injector-cant-find-service-when-loading-customexceptionhandler