# Angular 2 injector can't find Service when loading CustomExceptionHandler

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

When trying to inject a service into my CustomExceptionHandler, the Angular injector cannot find the service.

The error: `Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for CustomExceptionHandler: (?).`

The setup:

**CustomExceptionHandler**

```
import { ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';

import { ServiceA } from '../services/a.service';

export class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {

  constructor(private serviceA: ServiceA) {
    super(null, null);
  }

  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
      //do something with the service
  }
}
```

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceA,
    { provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: CustomExceptionHandler },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: `import { Service } from '../services/a.service';` should probably be `import { ServiceA } from '../services/a.service';` (missing `A` in the service name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** `ExceptionHandler` was renamed to `ErrorHandler` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239028/217408

**orgiginal**

Add `@Injectable()` to your CustomExceptionHandler class.

Add CustomExceptionHandler as another one of your providers in the app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceA,
    CustomExceptionHandler,
    { provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: CustomExceptionHandler },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thank you both Gunter and ade for your answers.  it was the combination of both of these that fixed it.  You need to add @Injectable() and you need to list it as a normal provider in the app.module.ts in addition to listing it as a useClass to override the ExceptionHandler.  This leaves me with somewhat of a predicament for who to accept as the answer.  Whomever types up the combination of these will get it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `CustomExceptionHandler` and its dependencies to `providers` as well:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceA,
    CustomExceptionHandler,
    { provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: CustomExceptionHandler },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I've revised the error: `Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for CustomExceptionHandler: (?).`

Comment: this isn't it, the issue persists. thank you for your time though

Comment: thank you both Gunter and ade for your answers.  it was the combination of both of these that fixed it.  You need to add @Injectable() and you need to list it as a normal provider in the app.module.ts in addition to listing it as a useClass to override the ExceptionHandler.  This leaves me with somewhat of a predicament for who to accept as the answer.  Whomever types up the combination of these will get it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. I didn't start with 100k neither ;-)